# Play Framework WebSocket Async

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework-2.0, loops

I'm using a WebSocket end point exposed by my Play Framework controller. My client will however send a large byte array and I'm a bit confused on how to handle this in my Iteratee. Here is what I have:

def myWSEndPoint(f: String => String) = WebSocket.async[Array[Byte]] {
    request =>

```
  Akka.future {
    val (out, chan) = Concurrent.broadcast[Array[Byte]]

    val in: Iteratee[Array[Byte], Unit] = Iteratee.foreach[Array[Byte]] {
      // How do I get the entire file?
    }

    (null, null)
  }
```

}

As it can be seen in the code above, I'm stuck on the line on how to handle the Byte array as one request and send the response back as a String? My confusion is on the Iteratee.foreach call. Is this foreach a foreach on the byte array or the entire content of the request that I send as a byte array from my client? It is confusing!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... It depends. Is your client sending all binaries at once, or is it (explicitly) chunk by chunk?

-> If it's all at once, then everything will be in the first chunk (therefore why a websocket? Why an Iteratee? Actions with BodyParser will probably be more efficient for that).

-> If it's chunk by chunk you have to keep every chunks you receive, and concatenate them on close (on close, unless you have another way for the client to say: "Hey I'm done!").

Comment: That makes sense to me, I already have another endpoint setup that is a normal HTTP endpoint in my play controller and I'm using HTTP Post to send the byte array to the server. But the only difference is that with a WebSocket endpoint, I can use HTTP GET instead of a POST. If I use GET, I cannot use the Actions with a BodyParser. The main reason for me to consider uisng a WebSocket is to use a GET request rather than a POST request